# Get span text that has no attribute using Beautiful Soup Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm scrapping a website, and I am having trouble getting the text for a span. I have seen that you can use below to get the text:

```
    <span title="9 gold badges"><span class="badge1"></span><span class="badgecount">9</span></span>
    badges = soup.body.find('div', attrs={'class': 'badges'})
    for span in badges.span.find_all('span', recursive=False):
        print span.attrs['title']
```

However, the span I am interested in getting the text of has no attributes. How can I get the text?

```
     <span>Geolocation: 35.1391, -90.0536</span>
```

Comment: Could you add more HTML to the example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tag.text or tag.get_text()

```
for span in badges.span.find_all('span', recursive=False):
    print span.text
```

Example output:

```
>>> span = soup.find('span')
>>> span
<span>Geolocation: 35.1391, -90.0536</span>
>>> span.text
'Geolocation: 35.1391, -90.0536'
>>> span.get_text()
'Geolocation: 35.1391, -90.0536'
```

Answer (score 1):

to get all the span tags where there is no attribute try this snippet:

```
for span in badges.span.find_all('span', recursive=False):
    if not span.attrs.values():
        print (span.text)
```

hope this works for you.